# Tomahawk inputCalendar popup doesn't show selected date

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I have a Tomahawk inputCalender like this:

```
<t:inputCalendar value="#{overviewBean.dateFrom}" id="date-From" 
                renderAsPopup="true" popupDateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
                popupTodayDateFormat="dd MMM yyyy" popupWeekString="Week"
                renderPopupButtonAsImage="true" forceId="true" alt="Calendar"
                title="Calendar" monthYearRowClass="yearRowStyle"
                weekRowClass="weekRowStyle" maxlength="15"
                currentDayCellClass="selectedDayCellStyle" />
```

I can select a date from the popup calender and this date will be shown in the textbox from the calender.

No I have the problem that if I click again on the calender button to open the popup the date which is shown there is the date from today and not the date within the textbox.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I found the solution myself. The problem is the `popupDateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"` attribute. If I change it to `popupDateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"` it works fine. It looks like there is a problem with the "MMM" in the date format.

Comment: I think the format you specify here should be valid Java date format.For more info on this visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html